# What do I do if the draw pile is empty?

Tags: uno

When you need to draw (more) cards, and the draw pile is empty, what do you do?

Answer (score 9):

You reshuffle the discards to form a new draw pile.

This is specifically stated in [the rules](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/42001pr.pdf) (page 2, at the end of the section **GOING OUT**):

> If no one is out of cards by the time the DRAW pile is depleted, reshuffle the DISCARD pile and continue play.